# How to update footer with with dynamic content on each page?

Tags: php, css, princexml

In each page inside our PrinceXML pdf we need the content in the footer to change based on a php dynamic variable.

Is there a way to update the content in the footer for each page?

(Below is the css code and the div)

css:

```
@page{ 
    size: US-letter portrait;
    margin: 1in .5in;
    @top{
      content: flow(header);
    }
    @bottom{
      content: flow(footer);
    }
    @bottom-right{
      content: '';
    }
  }
  @page rotated{
    size: US-letter landscape;
  }

  .rotated-page{
    page:rotated;
  }
  /*pagebreaks*/
.page-break{
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.page-break-after{
    page-break-after: always;
  }

/* page_header*/
#header{
    width: 100%;
    flow: static(header,start);
}
.logo-line{
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.page-title{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* page_footer*/
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  border-top: 3px solid #5D1F22;
  flow: static(footer,start);
}
```

footer div:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class='footer-left'>Revision for <?= $this->manual_nm; ?> in <?= $this->revision_cycle; ?> <br>Submission Document printed on <?= $this->generated_date; ?></div>
    <div class='footer-right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull text from the page in order to fulfil the headers and footers.

For example, if I wanted the latest `h2` tag to appear in the footer, I could extract it from the heading using the following CSS.

```
h2 {
    string-set: title content();
}
```

The name `title` is a name you give - you could call it `heading`, for example.

You can then use this string in your footer:

```
@page {
    @bottom-left {
        content: string(title);
    }
}
```

Example adapted from [Using CSS Paged Media to Add Dynamic Headers](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201312/Blog/Using-CSS-Paged-Media-To-Add-Dynamic-Headers/).

Comment: You saved my day, I would add that you can use and #Id aproach so no need to have only one element h2, just the element with an Id you choose to pick to put in the footer.
If in the example of the question the Revision is in any part of the document it can be enclosed and given an Id, then used the same way H2 was used.